# Python Flask Cookie Session with Firebase - problem in setting cookies

Tags: python, firebase, flask, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-cookies#python) tutorial to create a Flask Application that authenticate a user registered in Firebase and manage his session through the token id.

The problem is that the `/sessionLogin` route seems to work only when is invoked with a GET request (and not POST as in the tutorial), otherwise it doesn't set the cookies on the browser (I'm using Chrome 90.0).

Any idea why it doesn't work? Thanks